# Placeing floats mid-paragraph, but without breaking sentences

Tags: floats, layout

I actually am content with latex' float placing mechanism. The only problem I stumbled upon was that when trying to place floats inside a paragraph, they more often than not disrupt sentences. I dont have a Problem with that, but apparently many people have.

Is there a way to modify the float placement that they dont show up mid-sentence?
The alternative would be to place content between paragraphs without float. But I really enjoy Latex' doing it, and also write pretty long paragraphs.

edit: I want to "quantize" the points at where inside a paragraph floats can be placed, that they are able to show up inside one, without disrupting the flow. I am aware of the question mine was linked to as a duplicate, however that is not what I want.

As David Carlisle has pointed out in a comment here, what I want is (probably) not possible, on a fundamental level.

Comment: Maybe start a new paragraph with `\noindent`?

Comment: tex works at the level of paragraphs and lines but has essentially no information about sentences. When inserting a top float it can not know if the line of text at the top of the page is mid-sentence